# how to change value of progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
                        temp_volume=temp_volume-2;
                        if(temp_volume<0)
                        {
                            temp_volume=0;
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            $('#inchat li.'+name_of_inchatting_class).css('height','97px');

                            $('#volume strong').text(temp_volume);
                            //$('#volume progress').attr("value")=temp_volume;

                        }   


  <html>
  <div id="volume">  
  <strong>60</strong>
  <progress max="100" value="60">
  </progress>
  </div>  
  </html>
```

I am trying to change the status of progress bar when the event happens
What is a right code to put in else condition statement?
Any thought? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/), not [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), to set an element's value.

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/jjjSf/

---

As a side note, that's not remotely how `.attr()` — or JavaScript as a language — works. You cannot use a function call on the left-hand side of an assignment statement. It is meaningless.